# laplacian of $1/\rho$ in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, harmonic-functions, laplacian

In spherical coordinates, I believe that the laplacian of $1/r$ is zero everywhere except at $r = 0$ or

\begin{align}
\nabla^2 \dfrac{1}{r} = -4\pi \delta^{(3)}({\vec{r}}).
\end{align}

where $r$ is defined as the distance from the origin.

Is there a similar delta type function at $\rho = 0$ in cylindrical coordinates where $\rho$ the radial coordinate? When I write out the terms I get

\begin{align}
\nabla^2 \dfrac{1}{\rho} = \left( \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial \rho^2} + \dfrac{1}{\rho}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \rho}\right)\dfrac{1}{\rho} = \dfrac{2}{\rho^3}-\dfrac{1}{\rho^3} = \dfrac{1}{\rho^3}
\end{align}

Therefore I expect that the $\nabla^2 \dfrac{1}{\rho}$ should equal $\dfrac{1}{\rho^3}$ when $\rho \neq 0$ and perhaps some delta function when $\rho = 0$.

Is there a similar relation for $\nabla^2 \dfrac{1}{\rho^2}$ or $\nabla^2 \dfrac{1}{\rho^n}$?

I am asking because I am considering the biharmonic equation $\nabla^4f = 0$ in cylindrical coordinates where $\nabla^2 \dfrac{1}{\rho}$ and $\nabla^2\dfrac{1}{\rho^2}$ appear. I would be interested in any published papers on this topic as well.

EDIT: I have redefined the radial coordinate in the cylindrical coordinate system as $\rho$ instead of $r$

Comment: see here http://skisickness.com/2009/11/20/

Comment: In two dimensions, $\log r$ works, if that's what you're trying to get at.

Comment: $r=0$ is a line, not a point, in cylindrical coordinates. Regardless of coordinates the delta function is at the origin.

Comment: @ian Are you saying that $\nabla^2\dfrac{1}{r} = \dfrac{1}{r^3} + \delta(r)$ so that the delta function is only relevant at $r = 0$?

Comment: @MrZ. Which $r$ are you talking about? It would really be helpful in this discussion if you could use, say, $\rho$ for spherical radius and $r$ for cylindrical radius. I normally use $r$ for spherical radius, but the result is not confusing because I rarely encounter cylindrical coordinates. But if I am using both, I switch to $\rho$ for the spherical radius to clarify.

Comment: @MrZ. Anyway, what I meant is that the actual situation doesn't depend on coordinates. Whatever coordinate system you write the function $f(x)=1/\| x \|$ in, its Laplacian is a multiple of the delta function at the origin. But if you write $1/r$ where $r$ is the cylindrical radius, you are looking at a very different object, which actually blows up on an entire line, not just at one point.

Comment: @ian I have clarified the question so that $\rho$ is the radial coordinate in the cylindrical coordinate system. I am looking for $\nabla^2 \dfrac{1}{\rho}$. Based on our discussion, it seems that it should be $\nabla^2 \dfrac{1}{\rho} = \dfrac{1}{\rho^3}+\delta(\rho)$ for any $z$ and therefore blows up along the line coincident with the z axis

Answer (score 0):

No, you're confusing the two meanings of $r$.  In cylindrical coordinates, you need to be differentiating $(r^2+z^2)^{-1/2}$. And the Laplacian in $\Bbb R^3$ will of course have the $\partial^2/\partial z^2$ term.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Your answer appears similar to Ian's comment above in that $r$ is a line in the $z$ direction, but Ian mentions that there is a delta function at the origin regardless of coordinates. I am considering a 2D problem that is only a function of $r$ and $\theta$ and has no dependency on $z$

Comment: When you write $r$ in spherical coordinates, you mean the distance from the origin in $\Bbb R^3$, not the $r$ in polar coordinates in $\Bbb R^2$. This is why many of us use the letter $\rho$ in spherical coordinates.

Comment: So if I change my notation to define $\rho$ as the radial coordinate and $r$ as the distance from the origin, then shouldn't there still be delta function at $\rho = 0$ in the plane where $z = 0$?

Comment: @MrZ. Yes: the cylindrical Laplacian of the function $f(r,\theta,z)=(r^2+z^2)^{-1/2}$ has a delta function at the origin, which is to say at $(0,\theta,0)$. But $g(r,\theta,z)=1/r$ is not harmonic on its domain.

Comment: The function $1/r$ is not harmonic (on its domain), whereas the function $1/\rho$ is.

Comment: @ian I am beginning to understand. In the spherical case $\nabla^2\dfrac{1}{r}$ is equal to $-4\pi$ times the delta function. Is there a similar constant for the $\nabla^2\dfrac{1}{\rho}$? Also how can I mathematically prove that there is a delta function at $\rho =0$